# How can I build node-webrtc and support H264?

Tags: node.js, webrtc

To support H264 , I found a way for `./node_modules/.bin/ncmake rebuild -- -DGN_GEN_ARGS='proprietary_codecs=true ffmpeg_branding="Chrome"'`

https://github.com/node-webrtc/node-webrtc/issues/431

And then, I flow the

> [build-from-source.md](http://https:/github.com/node-webrtc/node-webrtc/blob/develop/docs/build-from-source.md)

to download source code to build self.

I replace the /node_module//build/wrtc.node in node-webrtc-examples project. It does`t work. Throw an error ↑

By the way . The wrtc.node from npm is 20.1MB. But the wrtc.node which I build is 34.3MB. I think it must got sth wrong .

Even I only run `./node_modules/.bin/ncmake build` without other args. It also do not work.

By the way . The wrtc.node from npm is 20.1MB. But the wrtc.node which I build is 34.3MB. I think it must got sth wrong .

Here is the environments:
node: 14.15.1
GCC: gcc version 9.3.0
cmake: 3.12.4
python: 2.7.18
gcc: 9.3.0
system: Linux VM-0-3-ubuntu 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
ubuntu version: 20.04

Do i build any thing wrong ?

Thanks for support !